# Cumulative count of names from two separate columns

Tags: r

I have a data set in chronological order which I have imported to R using:

```
mydata <- read.csv(file="test.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Two of the columns in the data set are 'winner' and loser'. Each row in the data is a tennis match.

What I am looking to do is to add two columns which give me a cumulative count of the total matches the player in the 'winner' column has played up to and including the match on that row. And the same count for the 'loser' in that row.

So for example it would look like this:

```
winner loser winner_matches loser_matches
tom    andy        1             1
andy   greg        2             1
greg   tom         2             2
```

I hope that makes sense.

I have tried using the following code but can't get it to work across both columns:

```
ave(mydata$winner_name==mydata$winner_name, mydata$winner_name, FUN=cumsum)
```

So the data below is the first 10 rows of around 20,000.

[image: this is how mydata looks]

Comment: What is your expected otutput

Comment: So currently the winner_matches and loser_matches columns aren't in my data, they are what I want to achieve from counting the names across both columns cumulatively

Comment: Ok, so do you mind sharing what the current `mydata` looks like then?

Comment: @Masoud You shouldn't add tags based on answers. They should only pertain to the question. I don't think [tag:dataframe] is needed here and the other two don't come up in the question.

Comment: @Frank I have a slight disagreement about this. There are meta posts talking about this issue. Of course tags should not be based on answers but there are exceptions that I think this one falls within them. Still a controversial thing. I will leave the question with your latest edit. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) base** Define a function which counts matches up to the ith row for the indicated player and then apply it for the winner and loser matches separately.  No packages are used:

```
count_matches <- function(i, player) {
    with(DF[1:i, ], sum(winner == player | loser == player))
}
n <- nrow(DF)
transform(DF, winner_matches = mapply(count_matches, 1:n, winner),
              loser_matches = mapply(count_matches, 1:n, loser))
```

giving:

```
  winner loser winner_matches loser_matches
1    tom  andy              1             1
2   andy  greg              2             1
3   greg   tom              2             2
```

**2) sqldf** A different solution can be obtained using sqldf upon realizing that this problem can be solved with a self-join on a complex condition like this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.winner, 
              a.loser, 
              sum(a.winner = b.winner or a.winner = b.loser) winner_matches,
              sum(a.loser = b.winner or a.loser = b.loser) loser_matches
       from DF a join DF b on a.rowid >= b.rowid
       group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  winner loser winner_matches loser_matches
1    tom  andy              1             1
2   andy  greg              2             1
3   greg   tom              2             2
```

**Note:** The input used, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "winner loser 
tom    andy
andy   greg
greg   tom"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get number of times that each player won or lost by `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, winner_matches_won := seq_len(.N), by=(winner)]
setDT(dat)[, loser_matches_lost := seq_len(.N), by=(loser)]

dat

#    winner loser winner_matches_won loser_matches_lost 
# 1:    tom  andy                  1                  1 
# 2:   andy  greg                  1                  1 
# 3:   greg   tom                  1                  1 
# 4:   greg   tom                  2                  2 
# 5:    tom  greg                  2                  2
```

***Data:***

```
dat <- structure(list(winner = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("andy", 
                                                                           "greg", "tom"), class = "factor"), loser = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                  3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("andy", "greg", "tom"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("winner", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "loser"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I'd do `DT = melt(setDT(DF)[, match := .I], id="match", measure.vars = patterns("^(winner|loser)$"), variable.name = "outcome", value.name = "name"); DT[order(match), nth_match := rowid(name)]` or similar. You could use `dcast` to get back to the OP's (bad) wide format from there, I guess.

Comment: @Frank Thank you frank. This somehow messed up the order (not really). But you're right. I can get the wide format.

Answer (score -1):

You're really close to getting `ave` to work. The `cumsum` function doesn't know how to handle text so I created a dummy column that's equal to 1 for each row. That gives `cumsum` something to count.

Here's a sample dataframe.

```
mydata <-
  data.frame(
    winner = c("tom", "andy", "greg", "tom", "gary"),
    loser = c("andy", "greg", "tom", "gary", "tom"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

And here's the code to add the two new columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- mutate(mydata, one = 1) # Add dummy column

# Use ave() to calculate both the wins and losses
mydata$winner_matches <- ave(x = mydata$one, mydata$winner, FUN = cumsum)
mydata$loser_matches  <- ave(x = mydata$one, mydata$loser, FUN = cumsum)

mydata <- select(mydata, -one) # Remove dummy column
```

Comment: The question asks for the number of matches played by the winner and separately by the loser but this does not give that.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes. It provides number of matches won and lost by loser and winner. Like my answer.

Comment: It gives the number of matches won by the winner and lthe number of matches lost by the loser but the question asks for the number of matches played by the winner and the number of matchs played by the loser.